# missing } after property list in my ajax method///

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

```
function LoadAdvListPage() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: <%= generatecharts %> ,
        data: {

        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    LoadAdvListPage();
});
```

Above is my java script function which calls the Ajax method but don't know some how its throwing error like `missing } after property list`

can anybody guide me whts the problem?

Comment: Q: Have you tried serving the page from your .jsp server (Tomcat) and doing a "view source" to example the actual HTML + Javascript your browser is seeing?  Have you looked at it under Firebug?  Q: If not, why not?  PS: your curly braces *don't* match ... and Firebug would have shown you where in less time than you took to make this post.  IMHO..

Comment: Test it: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/7PhaA/ It does not create any error.

Comment: Seems like the `generatecharts` returns string that broke JSON notation. Try to place it into parentheses: `"<%= generatecharts %>"`

Comment: OMG. If you have trouble with opening and closing you can use notepad++ and post your code there it will guide you with opening/closing tags so that you can easily see which one has no matching opening or closing symbol.

Comment: I guess you are using the jsp expression tag "<%= generatecharts %>"
so make sure it is giving you correctly formatted url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if something is above code you posted but here is an extra }

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : <%=generatecharts%>,
    data : {

    },
    success : function(data) {
        alert("success");
    }
});
}   <------ this one you don't need if you don't have opening { somewhere up
```

Edit:

So there is opening `{` above. Try doing like @Yuriy Rozhovetskiy wrote in comment, it's url param so for sure it shouldn't be json, but `""` are still needed .

Comment: The extra brace was probably a red herring.  The problem might be whatever <%generateCharts%> returns. Or maybe something else. The point is DON'T GUESS!!!! The OP needs to familiarize himself with Firebug (or some equivalent). Or at least Notepad++. IMHO.

Comment: @paulsm4 You sure have a point and it's true what you wrote, but I'm also doing this to improve my skills and trying to solve question with no full information given may help me in my work too when I miss something :)

Answer (score 1):

you should try thisL

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    LoadAdvListPage();
    function LoadAdvListPage() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : <%=generatecharts%>,
            data : {

            },
            success : function(data) {
                alert("success");
            }
        });
    };

});
```

Comment: Why do you call `LoadAdvListPage` again?

Comment: no he just put the calling of the method to document.ready. His not calling LoadAdvListPage  again.